# How to click on an icon through xpath consistently using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Please see below the xpath expression copied from the developer tools.

```
//*[@id="parentDiv"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/div/profile-link-column/a/i
```

I want to click on the 8th table data in first row(actually its a small icon), so this works fine 3 out of 10 times.

Can somebody suggest a more reliable approach?

This is my HTML:

```
<td>
    <!--anchor-->
    <div class="animated-slide-in au-enter-active">
        <profile-link-column device-id="${value.value}" class="au-target" au-target-id="395">
            <a click.trigger="viewProfile()" class="au-target" au-target-id="55">
                <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
            </a>
        </profile-link-column>
    </div>
    <!--anchor-->
    <!--anchor-->
    <!--anchor-->
    <!--anchor-->
    <!--anchor-->
</td>
```

Comment: @zx485 that doesn't matter!

Comment: its not a timing issue I guess. I've added sufficient waits for the page load.

Comment: sample code in the fn. call  below                                                              Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.LinkText("Location")).Click();
Thread.Sleep(5000);
Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//*[@id='parentDiv']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td//i)[2]")).Click();            
Thread.Sleep(1000);
 By element1 = By.XPath("//span[@t='cooler_details']");

Comment: I have written an answer, check whether it works fine, if it doesn't work paste the error, If it's related to visibility error, then the problem is, `<profile-link-column device-id="${value.value}" class="au-target" au-target-id="395">
            <a click.trigger="viewProfile()" class="au-target" au-target-id="55">
                <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
            </a>
        </profile-link-column>` is hidden in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Use `css` here

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("i.fa.fa-newspaper-o")).click
```

check whether it works fine, if it doesn't work, then please paste the error, If it's related to visibility error, then I think the problem is, `<profile-link-column device-id="${value.value}" class="au-target" au-target-id="395"> <a click.trigger="viewProfile()" class="au-target" au-target-id="55"> <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> </a> </profile-link-column>` is hidden in your html.

Comment: Message: System.InvalidOperationException : unknown error: Element <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> is not clickable at point (1469, 786). Other element would receive the click: <a click.trigger="viewProfile()" class="au-target" au-target-id="55">...</a>
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)

Comment: Then something is hiding your element , checking any screen or pop-up comes to hide that element.

Comment: actually the table grid is at the bottom of the page. I don't see any other popups or screens hide them. Using toggle xpather, I'm able to find all those icons using the xpath expression. The below also works fine sometimes, but rarely as I said 3 out of 10 times.                        Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//i[@class='fa fa-newspaper-o']")).Click();

Answer (score 0):

To click on the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the element to be clickable as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//td/div[@class='animated-slide-in au-enter-active']/profile-link-column[@class='au-target']/a[@class='au-target']/i[@class='fa fa-newspaper-o']"))).Click();
```